# ReactJS - Why redux-thunk calls an API function AFTER render all components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with React since a few weeks ago, I have faced an issue on an asynchronous API calling, I've read there's an alternative way to handle this issue smoothly, it's 'redux-thunk'. So I installed it by using npm and I added it to my action creator, not a reducer, like this below:

```
export function fetchDataSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
    data
  }
export function fetchData(url) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if(!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(data)))
        .catch(() => dispatch(fetchHasErrored(true)));
     };
}
```

This is my action creator and I've declared 'data', which is in **fetchDataSuccess(data)** function, in my component by using **mapStateToProps**, let's say there are 3 components in my project.

> App.js: **used connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)**
>   Component_level1: **deliver data from App.js to Component_level2**
>   Component_level2: **receive data from Component_level2** and button
>   Component_level2: also **fetchData(API_URL)** in componentDidMount()

So, I tried to log out to the screen, the whole flow seemed like this

App.js Will Mount
Component_level1 Will Mount
Component_level2 Will Mount
Component_level2 Did Mount
fetchData(API_URL) is called
Component_level1 Did Mount
App.js Did Mount

This is the flow that I have understood so far by component life cycle. If you see well, there's console.log(response); in fetchData from my action creator, that worked because I've confirmed it on the screen and there's button component in Component_level2 which has onClick method that prints data out to the screen and it worked too. 

**But the problem is I want data to be stored in my variables or somewhere BEFORE rendering the component that needs to use that data to show users**

I am really frustrated and desperate. Anyone help me out to work this out please?

Comment: p.s, the API_URL that I used for test is http://5826ed963900d612000138bd.mockapi.io/items

Comment: p.s.2. When I click the button, I get json data, but when I do like this, 'return(<div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}</div>), nothing is shown..

Comment: the behaviour is what your code wants, you set the fetch on cDM lifecycle so it should log after that cycle. if you want it to fetch before rendering use cWM (componentWillMount) lifecycle then. hope helps

Comment: @ReiDien I tried that now but the result is same.. :(

Comment: you also have the option to fetch data on App component add it into the componentWillMount so everything else should wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank @ReiDien for his/her time for me.

I found the way to solve this problem. I hope this would be helpful for everybody who were suffered by this issue and who searched for the answer desperately.

It's a summary for people, the issue that was stressing me out was:

- My project was built by react-redux  and it has redux-thunk as a middleware
- There's a problem exactly like this below
  [image]
- I've applied redux-thunk into my app, it didn't work  though :(
- API calling function was on componentDidMount() as most of guide posting are suggesting

So, here we are. First of all, you need to understand the basic concept of components life cycle of React.js, if you haven't grasp it yet, please refer this image.
[image]

So, I put some code into shouldComponentUpdate() function to let my app know that some data have been changed, but somehow it completely didn't work, my code was this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return (JSON.stringify(nextProps.item) != JSON.stringify(this.props.item)
}
```

This allows your app to optimize its whole process especially when it renders components again. Anyway, once I've got rid of this part from my code, my code has started to work properly like this!
[image]

**I am NOT sure if this way I've found is the appropriate way to work out, but anyway it worked. If you were looking for some solutions regardless of 'real'-answers, it might help you out, I guess.**
I will leave the link that might be good to you after read, as a comment and thank you if you let me know what's the correct way or some articles helpful for people. :)

Comment: https://medium.com/@mweststrate/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e#.b2i8wj2em